# Send POST with Retrofit to Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, post, server, google-cloud-messaging, retrofit

**GCMResponse:**

```
public class GCMResponse {

    public String multicast_id;
    public int success;
    public int failure;
    public int canonical_ids;
    public List<GCMObject2> results;

    public class GCMObject2 {
        public int message_id;
        public int registration_id;
        public String error;
    }
}
```

**GCMRequest:**

```
public class GCMRequest {
    public List<String> registration_ids;
    public Map<String, String> data;

    public GCMRequest(String title, String message, String icon) {
        registration_ids = new LinkedList<>();

        data = new HashMap<>();

        data.put("title", title);
        data.put("message", message);
        data.put("icon", icon);
    }

    public void addRegId(String regId) {
        registration_ids.add(regId);
    }
}
```

**RetrofitService:**

```
public interface RetrofitService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/")
    public GCMResponse GCMAuthorization(@Header("Authorization") String apiKey, @Body GCMRequest data);
}
```

**Main:**

```
private static final String GCM_SERVER_URL = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

private static void sendWithRetrofit(String apiKey, GCMRequest gcmRequest) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(GCM_SERVER_URL)
            .build();

    final RetrofitService service = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);

    try {
        GCMResponse gcmResponse = service.GCMAuthorization("key=" + apiKey, gcmRequest);
        System.out.println(gcmResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GCMRequest gcmRequest = new GCMRequest("Title", "message", "" + R.drawable.icon1);
    gcmRequest.addRegId("APA91bGL1GJ9eYGEIkGgcCXTOnMd_WPbacJH9UhztOWplcGcRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    GCMPoster.post(API_KEY, gcmRequest);
}
```

When i send POST to GCM with Retrofit, it always return response **"400 InvalidTokenFormat"**,  there is no Doc in internet.

What am I doing wrong in my code? and what this response means?

Comment: How your `RetrofitService` was actually implemented? I dont see how you put a key name for `registration_ids` field.

Comment: @ztan i edited question, added main method using "registration_ids"

Comment: first of all check your request url in debug in response object - looks like https://android.googleapis.com should be the base url and /gcm/send - should be string in POST annotation. But this is not the root of your problem. Most possible you have wrong json format (that's what HTML 400 explains), so you'd better rewrite your GCMRequest with nested objects